# Select-Box :before pseudo-element not working

Tags: html, css

My CSS isn't working as I expected. Here you can see my code:

```
/*Select-Box*/
select#user_select
{
    background-color: var(--white);
    float: right;
    color: var(--dark_grey);
    width: 30%;
    height: 3rem;
    padding-left: 3%;
    border: 2px solid var(--dark_grey);
    font-size: 1.2em;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

select#user_select::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    background: var(--dark_grey);
}
```

Comment: Wrap it with div and apply :before there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `<Select>` or any other form Elements Like `<Input />` is not except the css **:before** or **:after**.

So you need to wrap it with `<div>` or `<span>` for using css **:before** or **:after**. then it's working fine.